# HTML <tr> table from variable

Tags: html

I am in need of help! I want to create a function that will pass the below variables into a `<tr>` table in html so I can export it to excel.

```
B20P:  [[B20P1]], [[B20P2]], [[B20P3]], [[B20P4]], [[B20P5]], [[B20P6]], [[B20P7]], [[B20P8]], [[B20P9]], [[B20P10]]     |    
W20P:  [[W20P1]], [[W20P2]], [[W20P3]], [[W20P4]], [[W20P5]], [[W20P6]], [[W20P7]], [[W20P8]], [[W20P9]], [[W20P10]]     |
```

I want it to look something like the image below.

[image]

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Are the vars always the same length? What did you try? What are the vars? A string from a JSON string? They are not valid JS variables. What are the `|` at the end supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a go with this

Assumptions:

- The data is one string
- `\n` is line delimiter
- `|` can be ignored
- `,` is cell delimiter
- First "word" in the line is the header

```js
const lines = `B20P: [[B20P1]], [[B20P2]], [[B20P3]], [[B20P4]], [[B20P5]], [[B20P6]], [[B20P7]], [[B20P8]], [[B20P9]], [[B20P10]] |
W20P: [[W20P1]], [[W20P2]], [[W20P3]], [[W20P4]], [[W20P5]], [[W20P6]], [[W20P7]], [[W20P8]], [[W20P9]], [[W20P10]] |`.replace(/ \|/g,"").split("\n");
const thead = [], tbody = [];
const cols = lines.length;
lines.forEach((line,i) => {
  const cells = line.split(' ');
  thead[i] = `<th>${cells[0]}</th>`;
  cells.slice(1).forEach((cell,j) =>  {
    if (!tbody[j]) tbody[j]='<tr>';
    tbody[j] += `<td>${cell.replace(",","")}</td>`
    if (i+1%cols === 0) tbody[j] += '</tr>';
  })  
})  
document.body.innerHTML = `<table><thead><tr>${thead.join("")}</tr></thead><tbody>${tbody.join("")}</tbody></table>`;
```

```css
table tr td,th {
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
}

table tr {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
}


td {
  min-width: 100px;
}
```